# Example of Measure of non-compactness?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fixed-point-theorems

I can't understand the following example of measure of non-compactness, which was given in a research article.

**Definition:** A nonnegative function  $\phi$ defined on the bounded
subsets of $X$ will be called Sadovskij functional if it satisfies the following for bounded subsets $M,N\subset X$ and $\alpha\in K$.

- $\phi(M\cup N)=\max\{\phi(M),\phi(N)\}$
- $\phi(M+N)\leq \phi(M)+\phi(N)$
- $\phi(\lambda M)=|\lambda|\phi(M)$
- $\phi(M)< \phi(N)$ for $M\subseteq N$
- $\phi([0, 1] ·M) = (M)$
- $\phi(\overline{co}M) = (M)$.

An additional property of a Sadovskij functional is

$\phi(M) = 0$ if and only if M is precompact,

which we call the regularity of . A regular Sadovskij functional is called
**measure of noncompactness**.

**Example:**
Let $X = L^p[0, 1]$ $(1 \leq p < \infty)$ be the Lebesgue space of
all (classes of) p-integrable real functions on $[0, 1]$ with the usual norm, and denote by $\chi_D$ the characteristic function of a measurable subset $D\subset[0,1]$.

Can someone kindly explain me the following;

-How can we prove that 
$$\phi(M) := \lim \sup_{mesD\rightarrow 0}
\sup_{u\in M}||\chi_Du||,\quad (M\subset X)$$
is a Sadovskij functional?

-How is it not a measure of non-compactness?

-How to show that any set $M$ which is bounded in $L^q[0, 1]$ for some $q > p$ satisfies $\phi(M) = 0$ in X, by the H¨older inequality. How such a set need not be pre-compact in X ?

Rather I'd be very thankful if someone can give very easy and simple examples of measure of non-compactness.

Comment: what does mean Sadovskji functional ?

Comment: I've added the definition.

Comment: Standard book: Józef Banaś, Kazimierz Goebel, *Measures of noncompactness in Banach spaces*, Institute of Mathematics, Polish Academy of Sciences, Warszawa 1979.

Comment: I couldn't find this book anywhere in my country and online it's very expensive. If you have a soft copy of this please share!

Comment: @Shinning Star 
You can find an answer for your question in the book "Measures of Noncompactness in Metric Fixed Point Theory" of "José María Ayerbe Toledano, Tomás Domínguez Benavides, Genaro López Acedo" 
where a construction of the measure of noncopamctness for sequence spaces is presented...I also have the book of Józef Banaś, Kazimierz Goebel, Measures of noncompactness in Banach spaces I can send it to you if you stil need it,